# Pandas between range lookup filtering

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My data looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({
    'x_range':['101-200','101-200','201-300','201-300'], 
    'y':[5,6,5,6], 
    'z': ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Fish', 'Snake']
})
```

How might I filter on an `x` value (that fit's inside x_range) and a `y` value to return an appropriate `z` value? For instance, if `x` = 248 and `y`= 5, I'd like to return `Fish`...

Comment: Importantly: I don't want to match x = '101-200' and y = 5. My x value will be something like 113 or 248.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add these values as a third column in your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple filtering exercise:

Save your dataframe:

```
df['x_range_start'] = [int(i.split('-')[0]) for i in df.x_range]
```

Add two columns for range start and end:

```
df['x_range_start'] = [int(i.split('-')[0]) for i in df.x_range]
df['x_range_end'] = [int(i.split('-')[1]) for i in df.x_range]
```

Filter to find values:

```
x_value = 113
y_value = 5

df[(df.x_range_start <= x_value) &(x_value <= df.x_range_end)][df.y == y_value]['z']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't love this, but I hacked together a solution:

Split:

```
df['low'], df['high'] = df['x_range'].str.split('-', 1).str
df['low'] = pd.to_numeric(df['low'])
df['high'] = pd.to_numeric(df['high'])
```

Filter:

```
x = 248
y = 6
row = df[(pd.Series.between(x, left=df.low, right=df.high, inclusive=True)) & 
(df.y == y)]
row['z']
```